# Flask hangs intermittently on data return

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm using Flask 1.0.2 in Python 2.7.5 in CentOS 7.4. From time to time (say, 20 or 30 percent of the time) returning a value from a route function hangs. I've verified that it gets all the way up to the return statement by putting a log entry just before (that log entry shows up in the log, even when the call hangs). It happens on all of my functions, so I'll include the simplest for the sake of clarity:

```
@my_app.route("/signingkey", methods=['GET'])
def signing_key():
    """
    signing_key:    Provides the client with the current signing key (the public portion of it) for the domain

    :return:        The contents of the public key
    """

    try:
        provision_app.logger.info("Providing signing key")
        return utility.get_signing_key(True), 200, CT_TP

    except Exception:
        return utility.get_exception_text(), 500, CT_TP
```

NOTE: CT_TP = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}

NOTE: utility.get_signing_key() returns a chunk of text as a str object

I've tried returning a flask.Response object, but that didn't change the symptoms.

I'm running the Flask app via WSGI in Apache 2.4.6-80. My WSGI file looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/my_app/')
# noinspection PyPep8
from provision import my_app as application
```

And my Apache conf.d file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess my_app user=my_app group=my_app threads=4 processes=8
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/my_app/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /opt/my_app/>
        WSGIProcessGroup my_app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The server is a VM (kvm) with 4 VCPUs and 8GB of RAM. This application is the only load that the server has to perform, and rarely picks up above 3% CPU utilization (this is expected to go higher when the app goes to production, but at this stage of testing there's virtually no stress on the server).

I'm considering just nuking the server and starting over again, but I'd really like to know what's going on with Flask.

Any help, thoughts, or observations would be most appreciated.

Comment: Use what is described in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#extracting-python-stack-traces to try and extract Python stack traces as to what it is doing at the time it appears to block.